# Removing similar items from 2 different lists

Tags: python, list

Is there a more Pythonic way to execute this code?

```
sim_inits = [1,100, 12, 3520, 1250]
prod_inits = [2, 101, 13, 14, 3521, 1500]
for t in range(len(sim_inits)-1):
    sim_loop_done = False

    for s in sim_inits[:]:
        if sim_loop_done == True:
            continue

        prod_loop_done = False
        for p in prod_inits[:]:
            if prod_loop_done == True:
                continue

            if abs(s-p) < 3 :
                sim_inits.remove(s)
                prod_inits.remove(p)
                sim_loop_done = True
                prod_loop_done = True
print sim_inits
print prod_inits
```

Output:

```
[1250]
[14, 1500]
```

I'm trying to loop over both lists and the moment I find a match (defined by a difference less than 3), I want to move to the next item.  I do NOT want 14 removed from `prod_inits` because the 12 from `sim_inits` was removed against the 13 in `prod_inits`.

The above code works, I was just wondering if it can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip one of the loops, and you can use `break` instead of `continue` to get out of the other one early without using the cumbersome flags you're currently using.

List slicing is pretty expensive - especially in the case of `prod_inits`, where you're duplicating the entire list to just remove one element from it. Cheaper to iterate by index and then use `pop()` instead of `remove()` to remove that index. Similarly, we can use a `while` loop to count through the list `s` (instead of a `for` loop) because it lets us accommodate for the elements we're removing by doing (we do `s -= 1` for this reason).

```
sim_inits = [1,100, 12, 3520, 1250]
prod_inits = [2, 101, 13, 14, 3521, 1500]
s = 0
while s < len(sim_inits):
    for p in range(len(prod_inits)):
        if abs(sim_inits[s]-prod_inits[p]) < 3:
            sim_inits.pop(s)
            prod_inits.pop(p)
            s -= 1
            break
    s += 1

print(sim_inits)
print(prod_inits)
```

After running this code locally:

```
>>> print(sim_inits)
[1250]
>>> print(prod_inits)
[14, 1500]
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, faster, cleaner more direct -- thanks